# Accessing a functional component's method from parent component via ref

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way I can access the method `triggerFoo` in Child from the Parent? This is the code I have so far:

```
import React, {createRef} from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

    const Parent= () => {
      let myRef = createRef()

      return (
        <>
          <Test ref={(ref) => myRef = ref} />
          <button onClick={() => myRef.triggerFoo()}>Click Me</button>
        </>
      )
    }

    const Child = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
      const triggerFoo = () => console.log('Foo')

      return <div>Testing</div>
    })
```

Clicking on the button does not trigger anything currently.

One condition in my code is that it must use callback ref in the parent component, since this problem is part of a bigger problem I'm trying to solve involving a third party package.

Answer (score 0):

Changed code.

```
const Parent= () => {
  let myRef = createRef()
  const triggerFoo = () => console.log('Foo')
  return (
    <>
      <Child ref={myRef} triggerFoo={triggerFoo}>Click</Child>
    </>
  )
}

const Child = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return <button onClick={props.triggerFoo} ref={ref}>{props.children}</button>
})
```